# Make the while loop test all the time

Tags: jquery, html, loops, while-loop

I'm working on a simple test that uses a while loop.

Here is the code:

```
var ishovered = 0;

$('a.hovertest').hover(function(){
    ishovered = 1;
},function(){
    ishovered = 0;
});

while(ishovered == 1)
    {
        //execute function
    }
```

How do I make it so that while loop is testing all the time and the function executes as soon as he hovers? (Yes, I know I can put the function in the hover section, I'm asking this for a reason)

It doesn't really have to be a loop though, I just need a function to execute as soon as ishovered becomes 1. Is there any way to monitor that?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/9s3zE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9s3zE/1/**

Use `setInterval` for this purpose. You're describing the behaviour of a "poller", by the way. A poller checks whether a condition evaluates to true. If true, a function is activated. If false, the default behaviour (possible nothing) occurs. It's not wise to use a `while` loop for this case, because the browser will freeze when the condition is true.

```
var ishovered = 0;
$('a.hovertest').hover(function(){
    ishovered = 1;
},function(){
    ishovered = 0;
});

var showresult = $('#showresult');
window.setInterval(function(){
    if(ishovered == 1){
        showresult.text("You hovered");
    }
    else if(showresult.text() == "You hovered"){
        showresult.text("Default text (not hovered)");
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: That's almost what I want but not quite. I don't want it to test on an interval I want it to be testing constantly so as soon as ishovered changes I can execute the function. (I do like the if statement, that's what I wanted, I just need it to test constantly, not on an interval) I guess it should be triggered by en event of some sort so it doesn't have to slow down the browser by testing 100 times a second or so.

Comment: An small interval (if 100ms isn't small enough, lower it to 50), almost instantly executes the function as soon as the variable is changed. Go try it. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9s3zE/1/